# Wine: wininet.dll sends request for any domain to 127.0.0.1

Tags: wine

**Thanks to @Taylor and @Olli I fully revised my question.**

Hi,

I'm developing a windows application in ubuntu. Everything is fine. The only problem is that every web call I perform with `wininet.dll` is sent to localhost instead of target server.

I have no idea what's the problem and how to force wininet.dll to resolve domain name correctly.

I also created the hosts file in `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` and set domains and IPs manually; but did not help.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/etc/hosts` to do same thing. Format is at least almost the same, and there is examples in that file already in place.

Comment: If you mean the Ubuntu's /etc/hosts I should say it does not apply on the application running by Wine. Here is the problem.

Comment: @takpar: that's weird, because in my Debian it works without any problem. Clearly YMMV.

Comment: you were right. my problem was from somewhere else.

Comment: @takpar: nice, hopefully either answer will provide you a solution. Winetricks approach is better, if you do not want same entries for your Linux applications.

Answer (score 1):

apt://Winetricks has an option to create an empty hosts file in your wine directory, which you can then edit in the same manner.

You could try the wininet.dll from windows. I believe there is a copy on dllfiles.com (not sure if this link is correct since I am calling from memory). In wine, you will have to set the dll to native then builtin (and remember to create a backup of wine's copy of the dll before installing).

Comment: you mean I should just create a hosts file in the same structure and it will do the job?

Comment: essentially yes. Winetricks can do that for you, and it is best if you let it do that for you :)

Comment: +1 for introduce winetricks. (the link you provided is corrupted. please fix it.)

Comment: kk I tried to use aptlink :P but I'm on firefox 4 lol (works fine on chromium).

Comment: Note download DLLs and other windows environment stuff from the internet is often A REALLY BAD IDEA.... any DLLs need to be from a trustworthy source

Comment: @Wilf be that as it may, I've never run into any trouble with that site. Plus, if you're going to use Windows software, you should be prepared for the insecurities.